# How to serve development wordpress site using wp-cli on macOS

Tags: wordpress

Is there any easy way to serve a wordpress site on my machine on macOS other than MAMP stuck? Maybe php -S or python SimpleServer?

Comment: Mac OS X has everything you need. Have a look of this https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

Comment: You probably mean VVV Varying Vagrants, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com). It's a cross-platform application.